# How to get Category list in Laravel like WordPress style

Tags: php, wordpress, laravel, categories, taxonomy

I have categories table

#### categories table structure looks like this:

```
id - title - desc -  parent_id - others_column    
1  - title - desc -    null    -   others  
2  - title - desc -    1       -   others
```

I have tried to query, Project Controller looks like this.

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request; 
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller; 
use App\Category;  

class CategoriesController extends Controller { 
    public function index(Request $request) { 
        Category::with('childs')->get();  
   }
}
```

And Category Model Look like this:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model; 
class Category extends Model { 
    public function childs() {
        return $this->hasMany(self::class, 'parent_id')
    }
}
```

I'm getting result looks like this:

```
[ {  
  "id":1,
  "name":"Category one",
  "slug":"category-one",
  "parent_id":0, 
  "childs":[  
     {  
        "id":2,
        "name":"Category one one",
        "slug":"category-one-one",
        "parent_id":1, 
     }
 ] } ]
```

But I wanna get results WordPress style looks like this:

[image]

[image]

Now anyone can help me to get the proper results.

Thanks

Comment: the image was it gotten when you die dump the request?

Comment: No, I just expect the result like the image. I created it customly.

Comment: so you need the html markup to output the dark image result in the wordpress style

Answer (score 0):

```
class CategoriesController extends Controller { 
    public function index(Request $request) { 
        Category::all();  
   }
}
```

then you should use foreach loop and find parent and child in the loop then indent children below parents:

```
<ul>
                  @foreach($categories as $category)
                        @if ($category->parent_id === 0)
                            <li>- {{ $category->name }}</li>
                            @if (count($category->childs))
                                <ul>
                                    @foreach ($category->childs as $sub)
                                        <li>-- {{ $sub->name }}</li>
                                        @if (count($sub->childs))
                                            <ul>
                                                @foreach ($sub->childs as $child)
                                                    <li>--- {{ $child->name }}</li>
                                                @endforeach
                                            </ul>
                                        @endif
                                    @endforeach
                                </ul>
                            @endif
                        @endif
                    @endforeach
</ul>
```